# fetch svn log through a batch file from the server repository

Tags: svn, shell, tortoisesvn

I need to download a copy of all the commits made in the last 2 hours.This has to run evry 2 hrs,so obviously we have to have a batch file that should be put into the Windows task scheduler.I think svn log will be enough to give the details of Commits.Since I am new to Subversion, i dont know what how to connect and fetch the data from the Repository url from my machine(remote Machine).Please help

Comment: How are you connecting to the repo from your machine? svn+ssh, http, svnserve?

Comment: i am doing it through svnserver installed in my machine.

Comment: And the scheduled task is supposed to run from your local machine rather than from the server?

Comment: yes...the batch file should help connect to the repository(https://svn//...) and then execute the command to fetch the data into the local machine again.

Comment: I think that to create a log in XML format: "svn log --xml -v svn://some/url > svnlog.xml " - these lines are required.But will that be enough to connect to the svn repository.

Comment: If you have a user/pass you might try from the command line `svn ls svn://username:password@repo/path`  If that works, you can use those credentials in your batch file.

Comment: Since you'll likely need a way to log into it. That works over http, but I've never tried it with `svn://`

Answer (score 0):

If log command must be authenticated, you have to add to svn log parameters

```
  --username ARG           : specify a username ARG
  --password ARG           : specify a password ARG
```